# How to save selected checkedbox with corresponding textbox into the database

Tags: php, laravel

'  Here's an example of how i generate my textbox and checked box:'

```
 @foreach ($data1 as $data)              
 <input type="checkbox"  name="check_list[]" value="{{$data->course_unit}} " 
 price="{{$datas->course_unit}}">

 <input type="text" name="check_list[]" data value="{{$data->course_code}}"> 

 <input type="text" name="check_list[]" data value="{{$data->course_title}}"> 

 @endforeach
```

'[That is the output/image of my code][the problem is now how to save selected checked box with their corresponding textbox into differenet field in the database] '

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish here. Your HTML code is quite invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Get selected checkbox value like this in php

```html
@foreach ($data1 as $data)              
<input type="checkbox"  name="check_list[]" {{(isset($Detail->data) && 
        in_array($data,$array))?'checked="checked"':''}} value="{{$data}}">
   <input type="text" name="check_list[]" data value="{{$data}}">
                                                                        <br><br>
 @endforeach
```

in $data1 has selected checkbox values

```html
$data1 = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'];
```